# Meaning of 本当っぽいです

Tags: meaning

The sentence is "本当っぽいです", it's used to answer against a somewhat incredible statement, so I assume it contains a bit of sarcasm on it, and that is what I want to confirm.

I know that っぽい mean that something is "like" something else, like 子供っぽい meaning childish.

So on this case, I assume that 本当っぽい is used here as "something that looks like the ***thing***, but probably isn't but thing ***itself***", so on this case it would look like truth without being truth itself, thus being a lie, is that correct or I'm misunderstanding the meaning of っぽい on this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This -っぽい is merely a hedge used to decrease the level of certainty. The author avoided saying "that's true" definitively.

- 本当です。 That's true.
- 本当っぽいです。 Looks like that's true.
- ダメです。 It doesn't work.
- ダメっぽいです。 Looks like it doesn't work.

Note that っぽい does not sound negative or sarcastic by itself. 子供っぽい can be used with a real child in a positive way. っぽい sounds relatively more informal and colloquial than のよう or みたい, though.